# Java Audio API Stop Playback after Looping

Tags: java, audio, playback

I have written this code which loops the audio one time and then the file continues playing

```
public void playNextSecond(long startFrame) {
    //Get the number of frames for one second
    float sampleRate = audioStream.getFormat().getSampleRate();

    //Set the current playback time to the start of the loop section
    clip.setFramePosition((int)startFrame);

    //Set up the looping segment
    clip.setLoopPoints((int)startFrame, (int)(startFrame + sampleRate));

    //Loop one time
    clip.loop(1);
}
```

I would like playback to cease after the loop is complete. Is there anyway to do this? Alternatively, is there anyway to play until a specific frame?

Comment: The code you are showing looks like it should play one second. Am surprised if it doesn't. One way play to a specific frame is to count frames as you go, which would require using a SourceDataLine as an output. The first code example at the following link (Java Tutorials, using Files and Format Converters) shows a way to count frames. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html

Comment: "Why? This will just play the entire file. I want to play a segment and ONLY that segment without playing the entire file": you are not paying anything here do you undrstand that?? so go jump your business now